# phonegap save xml file local

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, cordova

How can i save files local on the device with phonegap?
i make an ajax call to an external address but i want to make 2 ajax call, one to save the xml file and on success i want to do another ajax call but to the local file i just saved? Did u understand?

---

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: this.settings.dataLocation + (this.settings.dataType === 'jsonp' ? (this.settings.dataLocation.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=?' : ''),
            // Passing the lat, lng, and address with the AJAX request so they can optionally be used by back-end languages
            data: {
                'origLat': lat,
                'origLng': long,
                'origAddress': address
            },
            cache: true,
            dataType: dataTypeRead,
            jsonpCallback: (this.settings.dataType === 'jsonp' ? this.settings.callbackJsonp : null)
        }).done(function(p) {
            d.resolve(p);

            // Loading remove
            if (_this.settings.loading === true) {
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('.wrapper').show();
            }
            $('h3.search-for').text(address);
            localStorage.setItem('CurrentAddress', address);

        }).fail(d.reject);
        return d.promise();
    },
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to save the file as JSON rather than XML? as it is easier to parse JSON as you are using PhoneGap.

**Load JSON file to disk**

You can use FileWriter.write to save JSON data to disk. JSON is a text based file anyway so there is no need to set the mime type.

```
function win(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        console.log("write success");
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
};

var fail = function(evt) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

entry.createWriter(win, fail);
```

**Read JSON from disk**

To load the file again use FileReader.readAsText, and in your "onloadend" handler, event.target.result will be your JSON data.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
  var myJson = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

**Note:** See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/alunny/1904992) for a better example of using fileWriter and FileReader or the [cordova docs example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter_write_quick_example)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, unfortunately it is not possible to save it as json when there is a call to an external server that is not mine .. :(